# Does the Microsoft Graph API provide access to the Change History (Cell level) of a Workbook or WorkSheet?

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

Inside of OneDrive you can open an Excel Workbook/WorkSheet and see the history of all the version updates (exactly what you see in DriveItem Versions). However, you can drill down into the version entry and see that a web call is made to get a list of all the cell changes made.

I really need a way to programmatically connect to an Excel Sheet in OneDrive and see all the changes made since the last time I looked. Then look at those changes and decide what I want to do with them.

I have looked in the documentation for v1.0 and the Beta. I don't think this is provided, at least not in a way I can recognize.  Thoughts? Suggestions?